# Is this a isomorphism $(\mathbb Z,+) \to (Z,+)$ where $\varphi(n) = 2n$? Why not?

Tags: group-theory

This is what I did :

a) $\varphi(x+y) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y) $:
 $2(x+y)= 2x + 2y$ so $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

b) $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$:
   $2(1) = 2(1)$  so $\varphi$ is one-to-one

c) $\varphi(x) = 2n$

$\varphi(1) = 2(1) = 2$ so is it onto? I say yes, but the answer says "$\varphi(n) \neq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$" so not isomorphic.
Why I say yes: for every element in $\mathbb Z$, the first group, there is a element $2n$ in the second group. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that there is no `n` such as `φ(n)=1`. Or `φ(n)=3`. So, the image of `φ` is not Z but a subset. You say *" for every element in Z in the first group there is a element 2n in the second group."* Right. But *for every element `y` in Z in the **second** group is there is an element `n` in the first group such as `φ(n)=y`?*

Comment: **Onto** means that for every element $y$ in the target set, there is an $x$ in the domain such that $\varphi(x)=y$.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply ypercube and Andre. I'll keep in mind to check for φ(n)=y . Now I understand better on the subset part.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this question results from confusion over the definition of *onto*.

In order for $\phi$ to be onto, we need there to be an $x$ such that, for every $y$, we have $y=\phi(x)$.  A simple counterexample is $y=1$; since $y$ is odd, there is no integer $x$ such that $y=2x$.